# How do I allow reflection on a shared IIS host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis, reflection, web-hosting

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622/nhibernate-and-shared-web-hosting/61649#61649) question a user replied that he was able to override the security settings on a shared host. I'm using the same host, but haven't been able to figure out how to change web.config to allow reflection. Is it a one-liner?

I'm using MVC + Nhibernate in my project, but I can't even get an Mvc "new project" template site to work, I suppose the problem is reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <trust Level="Full" />    
</system.web>
```

Note, however, that the section might be locked by machine.config.